# Using placement new, malloc, and free

Tags: c++, malloc, free, destructor, placement-new

Basically, I have a block of memory allocated using malloc that I want to start placing objects into using placement new.  I know that the destructors for these objects will have to be explicitly called when I'm deleting them, but I want to make sure that I understand this completely, and that I'm going about it the right way.  I'm almost certainly going to scrap this approach and go about things in a more straightforward manner, but I figured that I'd ask just for understanding's sake.

I have a class WordIndex that contains the following private member variables:

```
struct Word
{
    std::string word;
    std::vector<unsigned int> index;
};

Word* m_words;
std::string* m_lines;
```

Memory is allocated/reallocated for both pointers using malloc/realloc, and objects are being created using the following code (they're not overwriting any preexisting objects):

```
new (&m_words[pos]) Word();
new (&m_lines[m_numoflines]) std::string();
```

I have a destructor as follows, but I'm almost 100% sure that it's not doing things correctly, despite not showing any errors when running.

```
WordIndex::~WordIndex()
{
    unsigned int i;
    for( i = 0; i < m_numofwords; i++)
    {
        m_words[i].~Word();
    }

    free(m_words);
    free(m_lines);
}
```

My questions are as follows:

1. Considering the Word struct has a vector, is it enough to simply call ~Word, or do I need to call the destructor for the vector separately beforehand?
2. Do I need to call a destructor for a string (both for m_lines and for Word.word), and if so, how do I do that?  It doesn't appear to have a function like ~string that I can call.
3. Have I missed anything else?  I'm fairly certain that I have.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Considering the Word struct has a vector, is it enough to simply call ~Word, or do I need to call the destructor for the vector
>      separately beforehand?

You can write a destructor for your `struct` if you want, but in this case it's not necessary.

> 1. Do I need to call a destructor for a string (both for m_lines and for Word.word), and if so, how do I do that? It doesn't appear to
>      have a function like ~string that I can call.

Yes, you do. The destructor should be there, it's `typedef`ed from `basic_string`, so you should be calling `~basic_string()` on it.

> 1. Have I missed anything else? I'm fairly certain that I have.

The destructor for `string`.

Also, make sure you calculate the space for `malloc` correctly, you don't show that code, but verify its what its supposed to be.

Comment: Isn't `string` a `typedef` for `basic_string<...>`?

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  Can you provide an example of calling the strings destructor, since something like m_lines[0].~string(); doesn't seem to be valid.  EDIT: I just noticed that ~basic_string() DOES exist, so perhaps that's the correct destructor to call.

Comment: @jcptopi - added into the text

Comment: Alright, just to be clear, I only need to call ~basic_string() for the strings in m_lines, since ~Word() will call it for the string inside the struct, correct?

Comment: @jcptopi - you need to call the descructor for any constructor you called in a similar fashion. In your case it's all the strings in m_lines.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you're missing is the call to all the `string`s' destructors. It's called `~basic_string` (`string` is actually just a `typedef` for `basic_string` with some template parameters).

No, you don't need to call the `vector`s' destructors, because they're called by the compiler-provided destructor for your `Word` struct.